# Electron-Packager not doing anything

Tags: json, electron, electron-packager

So I'm trying to package an electron app using electron-packager. I have followed all the tutorials and have come up with using the following code and then running it in CMD using `npm run package-win`. When I do this however, nothing happens. It runs the command then hangs [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8wzl.png).
I have also tried packaging the default electron-forge application. This gets stuck in what I assume is the same place on;

```
√ Checking your system
| Preparing to Package Application for arch: x64
```

What do I have to change to make this work?

```
{
  "name": "exerunning",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . electron-serialport --overwrite --asar --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"CryptoApp\""
  },
  "author": "Patrick Voorhoeve",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^11.1.0",
    "electron-packager": "^15.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your cache, and reinstalling your modules.? `npm cache clean --force` `npm install`  Sometimes that can help.

Comment: Just tried doing a cache clear and the problem still persists afterwards.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. I can't seem to make a windows executable, but I had no problem with it about a month ago. Tried electron-packager version 15.0.0 to see if it would make a difference but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should have this in your package.json:

```
"start:electron": "ng build --base-href ./ && electron ."
```

Then run it; it will update your application status.

After that, run the package command:

```
npm run package
```

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to run the electron packager command, first, run the command **SET DEBUG=*** and then run **npm run package-win** command. It will display the logs in the terminal. There you can find the reason for getting stuck.

I also have faced this issue and found the reason for getting stuck using set debug command.